# Coding various X/Y coordinates for different devices with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uiimageview, storyboard, autolayout

I'm using a UIImageView for all iPhones with 40H,40W size. If I put this UIImageView in the middle of iPhone 4s storyboard, the x-coordinate=140. If I put this UIImageView in middle of iPhone 6PLUS storyboard x-coordinate=187

If i'm using auto layout with a single storyboard and a single ViewController class for all devices, yet both differently sized phones have different center coordinates, how do I code for UIImageView to be centered for both phones in the same ViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

Just add constraints to center vertically and horizontally

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work when you need the object to move to left side of screen, disappear off the screen and then regenerate from right side of screen.

Comment: No it does not. It meets the requirements of your question, which does not mention anything about this desired behaviour

Comment: If I want to work on all iPhone device, am I supposed to only used an x coordinates on Inferred storyboard instead of a specific iPhone size storyboard to target all iPhone sizes?